# Need a match an array value in mongodb and append into that

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
    "_id": "100",
    "menu": [
        {
            "type": "1",
            "isenabled": true,
            "items": [
                {
                    "key": "activity",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "criteria": [
                        {
                            "key": "account",
                            "value": [
                                "active"
                            ],
                            "isExclude": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "eligible": [
                        "QA",
                        "DE"
                    ],
                    "isItem": false
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

I have below types of docs in a collection.
Here i wanted to identify the eligible like wherever its ONLY "QA","DE", we need to add few extra value.
How can we do that in multiple docs at a time.

```
"eligible": [
                "QA",
                "DE"
             ]
```

Comment: what is your expected result

Answer (score 0):

use `$push`

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $push: {
    "menu.$[m].items.$[i].eligible": "US"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "m.type": "1"
    },
    {
      "i.eligible": [
        "QA",
        "DE"
      ]
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SoiFUQIJ81n)

Comment: Thanks a lot YuTing. It works fine. 

I tried below method to add multiple ata  time and it also works as expected. 

"menu.$[m].items.$[i].eligible": {
      $each: [
        "US",
        "WQ",
        "ER"
      ]